# How do I effectively compile audio messages in android?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, audiobook

I have many audio messages, by default it is treated as music by my android device. My question is how do I properly organize them, I want to separate my music and audio messages.

Right now I am using google playlist, when I say "Ok google, play music" it shuffles randomly and sometimes it chooses audio messages instead of music.

Do you have any recommendation on what apps to install so I can properly separate my music and my audio messages?